# gzip not working for aws s3 assets

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, gzip

I have uploaded javascript file to aws s3 bucket and for gzip compression, I have set following meta data. Also I have made file as public.

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

There is already one meta data is there

```
Content-Type: application/x-javascript
```

Error when accessing from browser

```
This webpage is not available ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED
```

Accessing url like this

```
https://s3-url.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/assets/js/angular.js
```

Comment: You might be facing problem due to server problem of aws i am also facing the problem with aws.

Comment: Did you actually compress the file using `gzip` before uploading it?

Comment: @Michael, No. I am not compressing before upload, do I need to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting `Content-Encoding: gzip` doesn't actually change your object's content encoding.  This is used to *describe* the encoding you have applied.

Setting it without actually applying gzip compression to the object will lead to errors like the one you encountered.  This is the browser complaining that you "claimed" (via the header) that the content was actually encoded with gzip, when in fact it wasn't.

Similarly, uploading a gzipped object without setting the header will result in an unusable download since the receiving user agent (browser) has no way to know how to decode the content, or that it even should try.

Note that when you gzip a file on your computer using `gzip -9 somefile.js` its name changes to add `.gz` onto the end, leaving its name as `somefile.js.gz`.  Remove the `.gz`, before uploading.  It isn't needed and of course you don't want to have to change your links.

The `-9` above specifies that gzip should use maximum compression, which is probably what you want.